# How to disassemble a Topeak JoeBlow Sport II

Tags: repair, pump, topeak

OK... I searched everywhere, could not find  a definitive answer.

I've had the pump a few years and use it a lot on several bikes.   I like my pump and want it to last as long as possible and I'd like to clean and re-grease its innards as a preventive measure,  the o-ring specifically but I cannot get to it.... I'm afraid I'll break it

Can anyone tell me how to get the cap off without breaking it?  or is there another way?  It's a JoeBlow Sport II (the yellow one)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Sylvain. Does http://www.cyclelicio.us/2011/bicycle-air-pump-repair/ or http://singletrackworld.com/forum/topic/topeak-joe-blow-sport-repair help? It's clearly intended to be serviced, since they sell a [Parts Kit](https://www.topeak.com/global/en/products/pump-replacement-kit/440-parts-kit)

Comment: How about you post some pics that show details not on the websites, such as under the bottom and any screws or threaded parts?

Comment: In my case grease did not work and I replaced the o ring with a R19 which is 23.5 mm internal diameter and 3.m section. I had to buy a kit of 400 O-rings to find this so hopefully this can save someone £10 as one washer should be pence.

Answer (score 13):

Well...  I tinkered carefully and was able to remove the top cap without breaking anything.

1) There are 2 small holes on the sides, right above the hose holder clip.  You must push in the tab that keeps the top cap secure using a pointy tool and turn the cap slowly clockwise. Here you see it with the tabs disengaged and showing the holes the tabs click into.

[image]

2) In the second image, you can see the tabs that hold the cap secure.
[image]

3) Then I was able to clean the the inside and clean/relube the O-ring (I used Slickoleum because  it's O-ring friendly... I use it to service my front suspension).
[image]

I think this pump is taken apart pretty much like any other cheap to midrange floor pump after all.

I hope this can help someone.

Comment: Good work. Mark this as the accepted answer.